# How can I calculate Average in Nifi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

How can I calculate the average of an attribute in nifi ? I am using the UpdateAttribute processor. I have 4 attributes that should be added and divide by 4 but how can I perform that in nifi?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @community question : my four attributes are $.main['temp'] , $.main['feels_like'] , $.main['temp_min'], $.main['temp_max'] i have declared these in evaluatejsonpath processor now i need to calculate the average_temp by adding all these and dividng by four , how do i do that and which processor should i use?

Answer (score 0):

I have assumptions that you have 4 attributes from **EvaluateJsonPath** processor:

- `temp`: `$.main['temp']`
- `fl`: `$.main['feels_like']`
- `tmin`: `$.main['temp_min']`
- `tmax`: `$.main['temp_max']`

Average attribute in **UpdateAttribute** processor:

- `average`: `${temp:toNumber():plus(${fl:toNumber():plus(${tmin:toNumber():plus(${tmax:toNumber()})})}):divide(4)}`